# Logo is not showing in header issue

Tags: header

I have issue with my site. My site is using Wordpress theme called FWRD, but some thing, when i upload logo in header, logo is not showing at all. Only blank space, and nothing more. How to resolve this issue, and uploaded logo to be visible n header. My site [URL](http://deil.cz/)

**header.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="<?php echo (is_admin_bar_showing())? 'wp-admin-bar':''?> ">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <?php 
    if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) :
        function theme_slug_render_title() {
    ?>
    <title><?php wp_title('-', true, 'right'); ?></title>
    <?php
        }
        add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
    endif;?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?> 
</head>
<body <?php body_class("layout-wide"); ?> onload="jQuery('header').animate({'opacity': 1})">
    <?php 
    $facebook_appid = get_iron_option('facebook_appid');
    if(!empty($facebook_appid)) { ?>
        <script>
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : '<?php echo esc_html($facebook_appid);?>',
              xfbml      : true,
              version    : 'v2.1'
            });
          };

          (function(d, s, id){
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div id="overlay"></div>

    <?php 
    $fixed_header = get_iron_option('enable_fixed_header');
    $menu_type = get_iron_option('menu_type');
    $menu_position = get_iron_option('classic_menu_position');
    $menu_is_over = get_field('classic_menu_over_content', get_the_ID());

    if(!empty($menu_is_over)) {
        if($menu_position == 'absolute absolute_before') {
            $menu_position = 'absolute';
        }else{
            $menu_position = 'fixed';
        }   
    }

    ?>

    <?php if($menu_type == 'push-menu'): ?>
        <?php get_template_part('parts/push', 'menu'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if($menu_type == 'classic-menu' && $menu_position != 'absolute' && $menu_position != 'absolute absolute_before'): ?>

        <?php get_template_part('parts/classic', 'menu'); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(($menu_type == 'push-menu' && empty($fixed_header)) || ($menu_type == 'classic-menu' && ($menu_position == 'fixed' || $menu_position == 'fixed_before'))) : ?> 
    <div id="pusher" class="menu-type-<?php echo esc_attr($menu_type);?>">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($menu_type == 'push-menu'): ?>
    <header class="opacityzero">
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <?php echo wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_request(get_template_directory_uri().'/images/svg/menu_icon.svg')); ?>
        </div>
        <?php get_template_part('parts/top-menu'); ?>

        <?php if( get_iron_option('header_logo') !== ''): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/'));?>" class="site-logo">
          <img id="menu-trigger" class="logo-desktop regular" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_iron_option('header_logo') ); ?>" <?php echo (get_iron_option('retina_header_logo'))? 'data-at2x="' . esc_url( get_iron_option('retina_header_logo')) .'"':''?> alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo('name') ); ?>">
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if(($menu_type == 'push-menu' && !empty($fixed_header)) || ($menu_type == 'classic-menu' && ($menu_position != 'fixed' || $menu_position == 'fixed_before'))) : ?>    
    <div id="pusher" class="menu-type-<?php echo esc_attr($menu_type);?>">
    <?php endif; ?>


        <?php if($menu_type == 'classic-menu' && ($menu_position == 'absolute' || $menu_position == 'absolute absolute_before') ): ?>

            <?php get_template_part('parts/classic', 'menu'); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="wrapper">
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: This is complete code from header.php file

http://pastebin.com/XNchihzH

i cant post code here, because is too big.

Comment: i have clicked on the given url and logo it is visible to me. It is logo http://deil.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/FWRD_logo-343434x23.png ?

Comment: Yes ita visible for second and then disappears.. This is what i see from mobile. Only blank space.         https://s16.postimg.org/f0gdmvhkl/Screenshot_2016_12_07_13_26_34_780_com_opera_bro.png

Comment: Anyone to help me with this? Small logo in fixed menu is white and its not showing..